# Select two different values from one row

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I want this table

*Booking table*

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Status |
+----+--------+
| 1  | R      |
| 2  | R      |
| 3  | C      |
| 4  | C      |
+----+--------+
```

---

To this total number of each

```
+----------+-----------+
| Reserved | Cancelled |
+----------+-----------+
| 2        | 2         |
+----------+-----------+
```

So far I got this -

```
SELECT Status AS Reserves 
FROM Booking WHERE Status = 'R' OR Status = 'C'
```

Output -

```
+----------+
| reserves |
+----------+
| R        |
| C        |
| R        |
| C        |
+----------+
```

Comment: This is called a pivot table and this question has been asked and answered on SO several times.

Comment: @Nahim Which database are you using?

Comment: The duplicate topic shows how to create a static (columns are known in advance) and a dynamic (columns are not known in advance) in mysql. The static version can be used in postgresql as well.

Comment: See a postgresql specific solution as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query

Comment: thank you, i wasn't sure how to phrase the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the logic from your `WHERE` clause into a `CASE` expression, and sum it over the entire table:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'R' THEN 1 END) AS Reserved,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'S' THEN 1 END) AS Cancelled
FROM Booking
```

Comment: This worked fine, thanks